# MYSQL How to do a count using a substring and left joining content.

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to do this query. I have looked all over and with little sucess.

I have 2 tables one is called numbers the other is called area_code
Here is what they look like. I know that there will need to be `substring(phoneNumbers,1,3)`

Table: **numbers**

```
phoneNumber 
4062081234
4062345453
2141234454
2101234555
```

Table: **area_code**

```
area_code       state      stateLong
214               TX         Texas
210               TX         Texas
406               MT         Montana
```

Desired output:

```
stateLong              count of phoneNumbers per state
Montana                2
Texas                  2
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can join using `left()`:

```
select ac.stateLong, count(*)
from area_code ac
    join numbers n on ac.area_code = left(n.phoneNumber,3)
group by ac.stateLong
```

In your title, you mention the need for an `outer join`, if you want to return all the states even if they don't have phonenumbers:

```
select ac.stateLong, count(*)
from area_code ac
   left join numbers n on ac.area_code = left(n.phoneNumber,3)
group by ac.stateLong
```